# how can I add a space between each consecutive pipes with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have an input like this:

```
|non-empty|||something|||
```

And I need to change is in a way that our wiki engine will display it correctly, that means that each "empty" field needs to have a space:

```
|non-empty| | |something| | |
```

I was trying to achieve this by using sed like this:

```
sed -E -e 's/\|\|/| |/g'
```

but this only added a space between the 1st and second consecutive pipe in each line (although the /g flag is there) Why is that, and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '|non-empty|||something|||' | sed 's/||/| |/g; s/||/| |/g'
|non-empty| | |something| | |
```

Given `|||`, when you do `s/||/| |/g`, the 2nd `|` is being processed as part of the first substitution so it's not available to match afterwards so when looking for the next `||` sed is starting at the 3rd `|` and so doesn't find a `||` starting from there. You can trivially solve the problem by adding a second `s/||/| |/g` since that'll start again from the beginning of the line and replace all `||`s that weren't found/replaced in the first pass.

Comment: so far I prefer this easy solution over 9999's, because this one works also in Mac

Answer (score 2):

Using sed and test

```
sed ':1;s/||/| |/g;t1' file
```

This uses test to keep looping over the line putting a space between and consecutive bars.

Output:

```
|non-empty| | |something| | |
```

Or similar in awk

```
awk '{while(gsub(/\|\|/,"| |"))1}1' file
```

Comment: add maybe the `g` in the `s///` command to do it in 2 pass maximum

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Woops, meant to do that when i added the awk command. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, simply change it to:

```
sed -E -e 's-\|\|- | | -g'
```

Note that you can use any character as a separator as long as you're consistent. Here I replaced `/` with `-` to make it clearer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, this will also add a space before and after the last/first non-empty field? For example: "|non-empty|||" => "|non-empty_|_|_|"

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this:

```
s='|non-empty|||something|||'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "") $i = " "} 1' <<< "$s"
|non-empty| | |something| | |
```

Answer (score 0):

`/g` flag is "global match" : match many times the pattern in same line. When you have three pipes your pattern with two pipes match the two first pipes and let the last one pipe alone. If you have four consecutive pipes, you'll match the two first pipes then the two last pipes : `||||` becomes `| || |`.

`/g` is not recursive flag. you want replace `||` with `| |` recursively. To do that, you'll need to use label and test : the answer from @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ is the good one with sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/|/| /g;s/| \([^|]\)/|\1|/g' YourFile
```

add a space after all `|`, remove spave where there is no `|` after `|`. By this way, no recursive and each pipe is treated without excluding the next one.
Posix compliant also

Comment: You missed off the closing `/`, also this doesn't work for me, leaves two || together like OPs. I don't think there is any way to do this with sed (with an arbitrary number of `|`) without using some form of recursion.

Comment: sorry in the hurry i forget th last `/` and put 2 pipe in first `s///`, it is 1 pipe in this first substitue just to avoid jumping 3 consecutive pipe